# How to test webpages on an iOS device

Tags: ios, web-testing

I can't afford an `iOS` device but users reported me that there is some issue in my website with the bottom navigation fixed bar for mobile with the `iOS` navigation strip at the bottom so how can I take a look at my website on an `iOS` device in order to fix it.

Comment: You can download Xcode and use the iOS Simulator, or if screen size is the only issue, most browsers' developer tools provide a way to simulate a mobile screen size.

Comment: I see mobile screen size in inspect tool but I users told me that my website navigation is conflicting with the bottom ios __ bar used to go to homepage.

Comment: I found that xcode is only for mac so I can't use it I have windows any other way??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a bunch of `iOS` emulators for **Windows** or **Browser**:

- [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io/)
- [Corellium](https://corellium.com/) (now paid)
- [Remote iOS Simulator for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator/)
- [iPadian](https://ipadian.net/) (now paid)

There are all free or have a free plan. Cheers!

---

**EDIT - 2024**

Well-known iOS emulators such as [Corellium](https://corellium.com/) and [iPadian](https://ipadian.net/) have switched to paid models. For budget-friendly alternatives, consider:

- [lambdatest.com](https://www.lambdatest.com/)
- [app.blisk.io](https://app.blisk.io)

Comment: Looks like Corellium and iPadian does not have a free plan anymore. Microsoft Remote iOS Simulator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/remote-simulator) will probably need a Mac computer. Just tested Appetize.io free plan and it worked great for simple web design!